# Go "unrecognized imports"

Tags: go, godeps

On fedora 22, I found that all the standard go libraries aren't visible on the path for go.

**NOTE** I have indeed cleaned my system of golang - so I'm pretty sure it's not a mixed package versioning problem  which often can happen when upgrading go.

**NOTE** The version of go I've installed is 1.4.2

I have been setting GOROOT=/usr/lib/golang, and GOPATH=(anything).

What internal directories in /usr/lib/golang should I look into to troubleshoot the missing libraries?

A simple example of the failures I'm getting are below...

`[jay@rhbd gopath]$ go get github.com/golang/example/hello
package github.com/golang/example/hello
        imports fmt: unrecognized import path "fmt"
package github.com/golang/example/hello
        imports runtime: unrecognized import path "runtime"`

and the corresponding go env:

`GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/jay/gopath/"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/golang"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/golang/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"`

UPDATE

As per the comments in this thread... It looks like I don't have ANYTHING under /usr/lib/golang/src.  Does this basically imply that my Go distribution is broken?  If so maybe the Go binary should fail fast when this is the case... ?

Comment: Exactly how are you installing Go? If you install from source, don't set `GOROOT`.

Comment: I've tried this with and without GOROOT.    What are some tricks i can use to really inspect the problem?   Why would GOROOT hurt the situation?

Comment: I don't know what to troubleshoot, since I don't know how you got here. If you used the official binary installation, all you do is unpack the tarball, and set the appropriate variables. *What steps did you use to install Go?*

Comment: yum install golang (fedora packages).  however, shouldn't there generally be a way you can see where go is looking for packages, to confirm/deny their existence ?  Typically in the java world, we might do something like use System.getProperties to print all the jars on the classpath, and then look through them one by one for packages.  I assume in golang there might be a similar low level way to manually find what packages that are supplied to a program at runtime?

Comment: You almost never use `GOROOT`, because it's baked in to the compiled `go` tools, and setting it is [almost always a mistake](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really). There's no "low level" way to look up packages -- there's only two places to look `GOROOT` and `GOPATH`. The Go stdlib sources should be in `$GOROOT/src`.

Comment: Hmmm. okay.  So, then your saying if GOROOT=/usr/lib/golang, and there is nothing under src/ then something is seriously broken with my go installation?  I guess that resolves the issue ... .

Answer (score -1):

**TLDR**

The final solution to my problem was as follows  (this maybe overkill).

`yum erase golang-src`

`rm -rf /usr/lib/golang/`

`yum install golang-src golang`

After installing golang-src, you should confirm that indeed under GOROOT/src/ there are several packages for all the standard go libs, i.e. the ones listed below.

**THE DETAILS OF HOW TO INVESTIGATE GOLANG INSTALLATIONS**

Obviously : `go get` gets and installs the source code you specify.  Most go libraries use the standard libraries, like `io` or `bytes` and so on.  Hence, a good test that your go distribution is installed correctly, and that your GOPATH is also set - is to run `go get`. For example  `go get github.com/golang/example/hello`  is sufficient to expose a flaw with GOROOT standard libraries.

The first thing to do is to check what GOROOT is out of the box in your isntallation.  It is available by running `go env`, which will give you all go environment variables.

In general **GOROOT** should have a `src/` directory underneath it.  However, if you have a broken go package, then some of these libraries might not be (for some reason) under GOROOT/src. That is, you **SHOULD** see the source directories there for the core go stuff, for example, from a healthy working go installation.

`ls /usr/lib/golang/src/
all.bash          builtin/          compress/         errors/           html/             libbio/           Make.dist         os/               run.bash          strings/          time/
all.bat           bytes/          ......    net/              regexp/           strconv/          text/`

Now, looking back at **my broken go installation**, it looked very different from what is above ... It looks like I don't have **ANYTHING under /usr/lib/golang/src** .  This basically means that my go package was missing some very important components, and almost any `go get ...` operation will thus fail, since none of the go standard libraries are in the GOROOT path.

As mentioned above -- **the end solution** here was simply to `yum erase golang-src`, `rm -rf /usr/lib/golang/` and then and `yum install golang-src golang`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me answer this ! 
I guess I'll have to go check out the  packaging of this distro and see why its excluding the  go standard library src/ directory.